# How to access controller method inside the same controller

Tags: php, e-commerce, opencart

i have method "A_method" inside the controller. and inside A_method i would like to call another method in same controller "B_method".how can i call method "B_method" inside "A_method"

```
function A_mehtod()
{

$rsl =  B_method(10);

echo $rsl; 

}

function B_method($data)
{


retun ($data+1);

}
```

please give me a solution in Php MVC. because i'm working on opencart and i'm new to it

Comment: Looks like You are also new to PHP, or at least to object oriented programming. Since OpenCart is build using OOP approach and MVC pattern I recommend reading about (or better learning) OOP PHP prior to developing something for OpenCart - though it is true that while developing for OpenCart You can also learn something - but without at least the minimum knowledge the learning curve would be too huge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $rsl = $this->B_method($data);
```

That's all. Have a nice day!!

Answer (score 1):

```
function A_mehtod() {

$rsl = $this->B_method(10);

echo $rsl;

}
```